# Como importar dados da clibboard para um data-frame no R

Tags: r, data.frame

Uma das vantagens de se usar planilha eletrônica é que podemos importar dados da clipboard.

Há alguma forma de se fazer isso no R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Mas tem diferenças no Windows e no Mac:

***No Windows:***

Você pode usar a função `readClipboard()`.

```
x <- readClipboard()
```

Isto vai colar os dados do clipboard como texto em x. Se os dados do clipboard forem tabulares (uma tabela, por exemplo), você pode usar a função `read.table()`

```
x <- read.table(file = "clipboard", sep = "\t")
```

***No Mac:***

No Mac, você vai usar a função `pipe` junto com `read.table`.

```
x <- read.table(pipe("pbpaste"), sep="\t")
```

Comment: Como é feito no Linux?

Comment: @GuilhermeD, não estou com um Linux para testar agora, mas penso que não seja muito diferente. De qualquer forma, sinta-se a vontade para colocar uma resposta complementar com a solução para Linux se você testar e descobrir a resposta correta.

Comment: Acabei de testar. Um simples `x <- read.table("clipboard")` resolve o problema, abraço.